# If-else condition fails when app goes to background

Tags: iphone, if-statement

I am working on an app in which I have used a table view. On this table view I have some information on  table header and i also customize the table header by putting some custom view on it.

```
if ([imageForCheckMark.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"crossCheckMark.png"]]||[imageForCheckMark.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark.png"]])                  
{

}
else
{
  imageForBackGroundOfHeader.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"head1.png"];               
}
```

On the above code i have matched the image with it's name and it gives me result according to the image i have applied on the header view. But if i am working  on this code and put my app in background and and comes to foreground this code give false value every time.

What I am doing wrong? Please advice me what to do to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *accessibilityIdentifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

accessibilityIdentifier is a NSString present as a property in UIKit which u can use to store the name of the image in UIImageView.**NO need to SubClass UIImageView for storing imageName.**

```
UIImageView *imv;
```

While you set the image into imageView set file name also.

```
[imv setAccessibilityIdentifier:@"ImageName"] ;
imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imv accessibilityIdentifier]];
```

When u are validation your condition just check:

```
   if ([[imv accessibilityIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"crossCheckMark.png"]||[[imv accessibilityIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"checkMark.png"])                  
        //Do this
    else
    imageForBackGroundOfHeader.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"head1.png"];
```

Answer (score 1):

How can you expect

imageForCheckMark.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crossCheckMark.png"] ?

These two are different objects.

Best way to do this is make new class derived from UIImage and use flag to differentiate image.

Comment: Couldn't get it i am just matching the name not objects.Please find the comment of Dave Albert on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523322/finding-image-name-loaded-into-uiimage-instance

Comment: In same thread, follow accepted answer by Marc W, Its solution for your problem too :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
[imageForCheckMark.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"crossCheckMark.png"]
```

with this

```
imageForCheckMark.image ==[UIImage imageNamed:@"crossCheckMark.png"]
```

so your condition will now look like this

```
if ((imageForCheckMark.image ==[UIImage imageNamed:@"crossCheckMark.png"])||(imageForCheckMark.image ==[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark.png"]))                  
 {

 }
 else
 {
     imageForBackGroundOfHeader.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"head1.png"];               
 }
```

Comment: It is not solving the problem it is same as previous.